# shouldInterceptRequest is not called when running Android 4.3 or lower

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm using a simple WebViewClient in a WebView in Android. I want to intercept requests when loading resources and thus I have overridden shouldInterceptRequest like this:

```
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {


    Log.d(TAG, "onInterceptRequest: " + url);

    // Do something important if needed
    //...
    // else go on...
    return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view,url);
}
```

The problem is that this doesn't work on all of my devices. On my Galaxy S4 with Android 4.4 it works all the time. On my Galaxy S2 with Android 4.1.2 it doesn't work at all. Any suggestions about this? The function shouldInterceptRequest is flagged as API level 11, so it should be safe on Android 3.0+

**Update**: I have now tested this on Android 4.3 and shouldInterceptRequest is not called on that device either. My targetSdkVersion is set to 19.

**Update 2**: More tests. It seems that shouldInterceptRequest is called when I'm using WebView::loadUrl, but not when I'm passing the html as a string using WebView::loadDataWithBaseURL.

Comment: Are you attempting to load local hosted files?

Comment: same here, i am loading html data not a url. Would this cause this behaviour?

Comment: If you are using WebView::loadDataWithBaseURL, pass valid baseURL, If you pass null you would not get  shouldInterceptRequest call back